# Accessing char attribute of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

in my code I have a function that can initialize new instance of a struct, which has a char attribute, and the same function returns a pointer to an instance.

But when I try to read the char attribute from different scopes, I get also different characters.

Below you can find my code and also the results.
Thanks in advance!

**Main function**

Here the character is printed correctly.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char line[] = "2-11 f: fjdfffmffffrff";
    char *pnt = line;
    Entry *entry = getEntry(&pnt);
    printf("(main) min %d\n", entry->min);
    printf("(main) max %d\n", entry->max);
    printf("(main) character %c\n", entry->character); <-----
    printf("(main) password %s\n", entry->password);
    printEntry(entry);
    return 0;
}
```

**Function**

While here the printed character is some random char.

```
void printEntry(Entry * entry){
    printf("(function) min %d\n", entry->min);
    printf("(function) max %d\n", entry->max);
    printf("(function) character %c\n", entry->character); <--
    printf("(function) password %s\n", entry->password);
}
```

**STDOUT**

Here are the results.

```
(main) min 2
(main) max 11
(main) character f
(main) password fjdfffmffffrff
(function) min 2
(function) max 11
(function) character L
(function) password fjdfffmffffrff
```

**Edit**

**Entry struct**

```c
typedef struct Entry {
    int min, max;
    char character;
    char *password;
} Entry;
```

```
char **separateBySpace(char **stringPtr) {
    char **ptrArray = (char **) malloc(ARR_PTR_LEN * sizeof(char *));
    char delim[] = " ";

    char *ptr = strtok(*stringPtr, delim);
    ptrArray[0] = ptr;
    int x = 1;

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (x >= ARR_PTR_LEN) {
            break;
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        ptrArray[x] = ptr;
        x++;
    }
    return ptrArray;
}


Entry *getEntry(char **stringPtr) {
    char **pntArray = separateBySpace(stringPtr);
    char *rules = pntArray[0];
    char *character = pntArray[1];
    char *password = pntArray[2];
    int *array = getRange(rules);
    Entry entry = {.min = *(array), .max= *(array + 1), .character = *(character), .password= password};
    Entry *pntEntry = malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    pntEntry = &entry;
    return pntEntry;
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of the `Entry` struct as well as `getEntry()`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65409584/edit) your question with an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There is a lot in this line: `Entry *entry = getEntry(&pnt);` that is not defined, but needs to be before any meaningful attempt to answer your question can be made.  Include a [mcve].

Comment: @bool3max  I added this function

Comment: Function `getEntry` returns the address of a non-static local variable. Using this address in `main` is undefined behavior. Probably the call to `printEntry` partially overwrites the data, that's why you see different output.

Comment: `Entry *pntEntry = malloc(sizeof(struct Entry)); pntEntry = &entry;` This discards the pointer returned from `malloc` and causes a memory leak. Then it causes undefined behaviour if the function is left and the address of `entry` is accessed lateron.

Comment: You are aware that there is no garbage collector in C cleaning up the mess the programmer created, aren't you?

Comment: Two comments have ask for a complete example.  Can you compile the code you have provided? `Build Status (so.prj - Debug)
  4 errors, 1 warning
 error: implicit declaration of function 'getRange' is invalid in C99. Make sure that you include the function prototype. 
    warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int' 
  error: expected expression
 error: expression is not assignable
 error: implicit declaration of function 'printEntry' is invalid in C99. Make sure that you include the function prototype. 
Build failed.`

Comment: @alk you are more than invited to explain more, instead of asking rhetorical question

Comment: The code (also) leaks the memory allocated here: `char **ptrArray = (char **) malloc(ARR_PTR_LEN * sizeof(char *));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `getEntry` returns the address of a non-static local variable. Using this address in `main` is undefined behavior. Probably the call to `printEntry` partially overwrites the data, that's why you see different output.

You try to dynamically allocate memory for the returned data with

```
Entry *pntEntry = malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
```

but you throw away the address to this memory and assign the address of your local variable with

```
pntEntry = &entry;
```

You probably want to copy the structure instead of the pointer. This would be

```
*pntEntry = entry;
```

---

Not related to your problem:

Your program should `free` all allocated memory when it is no longer used.

With the code shown in the question it is not necessary to pass the address of the pointer to the input string to `getEntry` and `separateBySpace` as a type `char**` because you don't want to modify the pointer. Passing a `char*` would be sufficient.

In `separateBySpace` you return an array of pointers that point to characters of the input string which gets modified by `strtok`. Later in `getEntry` you assign the pointer `password` to a pointer in your `Entry` structure. This means you should not change the string variable that was passed as an argument to `getEntry`, otherwise the `password´ string referenced in the returned` Entry` structure will change.

**Edit** (to answer a comment):

I think in `getEntry` you can `free` the pointer array allocated in `separateBySpace` because all values have been used or copied to the `Entry` structure.

At the end of the program you should `free` the memory pointed to by `entry` that was allocated in `getEntry`.

You must not `free` the memory `password` because this points to a character in your local variable `line`. Freeing `entry->password` before freeing `entry` would be necessary if you would allocate memory for a copy of the password, for example using `strdup`. This would also fix the possible problem that `entry->password` points to an element of `line`.

Comment: 1) Should I free first of all the pointer to the password, and then of the Entry?

2) I use this code in other place, where I read lines from a file and there the returned line is actually a pointer

3) I'm not really understand the third paragraph. You mean, later in code, it is better to not to change the string that I pass to `getEntry()`?